# From Mac to PC - Different Anaconda environments

Tags: windows, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I am a long time Mac/Linux user who has recently purchased a Windows laptop.  I have two completely separate Anaconda installations on my Mac using PyEnv which allows me to isolate them effectively.  Sure it wastes a bit of space on my Mac's hard disk, but I do not mind.

I am returning to a Windows machine after a long time, so I am not quite up to speed yet.  Is there a way to effectively isolate two different versions of Anaconda on Windows?  One for python 3 and other for python 2? I am frequently using different libraries and packages, e.g., pandas, etc. on both python 3 and 2 and also installing other packages either using 'conda install' or 'pip'.  What is the optimal strategy for managing two Anaconda environments for Python 3 and 2 on the Windows machine?  Once again, the disk capacity is not a problem since I have a one terabyte drive on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one central installation of Anaconda and use the native environment feature. Let's say you install the 3.6 version of Anaconda onto your machine, you can create an environment with the full 2.7 version of Anaconda like this:

```
conda create --name py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

And you can conda install whatever packages you desire into your environment.

Comment: I have a follow up question.  For the 2.7 version that I create as you show above,  will it have its own compatible versions of Pandas, SciPy, NumPy, etc.?  or it will point to the 3.6 versions of these libraries?  How does it work?

Comment: if you have activated the environment (works the same way as Virtualenv) anything you conda install will be compatible. If I "source activate py27" and then "conda install a_package" it will be the 2.7 version. Also, if you run the command I listed above the entire 2.7 version of Anaconda will be installed into your environment.