# Anaconda Select Environments Mac OS

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I'm running Anaconda 3 with Python 3.6 on MacOS 10.12.

I created an environment using python 2.7 and opencv using `conda create --name my-env python=2.7 anaconda`[(e.g. here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463013/from-mac-to-pc-different-anaconda-environments). I activated the environment using `source activate my-env` and installed `opencv`. Both creation and activation seem to have worked: the `anaconda3/envs/my-env` folder exists and my terminal says `(my-env) bob:~ alice`'.

But how do I get Anaconda to use the new environment?

I tried:

- starting the default `Anaconda-Navigator.app`, this just uses the default python path
- changing the path in my `~/.bash-profile`, but Anaconda still tries the default python path
- starting the `Anaconda-Navigator.app` located in the `my-env` folder, fails with the OS error message "cannot be opened"
- starting from terminal exits with the error message: FSPathMakeRef(~/anaconda3/envs/my-env/Anaconda-Navigator) failed with error -43.

Because I read somewhere that Anaconda 3 might not play nicely with Python 2.7, I tried the same workflow again, but creating an environment using python 3.5.4. Again to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean, how do you get Anaconda to use the new environment? Which part of Anaconda? Jupyer Notebook? JupyterLab? The regular Python interpreter? Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify. In the end I wanted it to work with spyder. The answer below solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there a two possibilities to run a program in an env once the env has been created with conda:

1. Through default anaconda-navigator (the GUI of anaconda), there should be a menu on the left, with the following options: Home, Environments, Projects(beta),...
   Simply klick on environments and choose/create a new one(see screenshot)

[image]

The "Applications on base(root)" can also be changed. If it does not display these options I recommend you to update conda.

2. Via terminal: activate the env as you mentioned earlier and then simply run the program you want, for example spyder, it should then use the right py version.

My default version of anaconda, the "root(base)" runs with python 2, therefore I added a few lines in my .bash_profile file to easily run python/spyder in either a default env or a specific one. maybe you can use something similar.

```
NONE='\033[00m'
YELLOW='\033[01;33m'

spy() {
    if [[ "${1}" == "" ]]
    then
        ENV="py36env"
    else 
        ENV=${1}
    fi

    source activate ${ENV} #enter env
    echo -e "${YELLOW}CURRENT ENVIRONMENT: ${ENV} ${NONE}"  
    spyder               #open spyder
    echo -e "${YELLOW}EXIT ${ENV} ${NONE}"
    source deactivate    #exit env when spyder is quitted
}
```

You can now run spyder in the env "XXX" by entering "spy XXX" in the terminal. Or the default one by typing in "spy".

Comment: Duh! Thanks, I completely overlooked that drop down menu, that solves it! Did not try the terminal-based solution yet.

Comment: Np. Try the terminal version though, saves a lot of time:) (I slightly edited it, now you can just paste&copy it if you want)